Unable to export only matched features after AddJoin Common - ArcPy
The exported featureclass called 'output_feature_class' contains all of the features from the input feature class even after joined based on COMMON, only want common/matched records as output.
For example input featureclass has 100 records, and the joined table has 15, after exporting the join featureclass contains all of the 100 features including 15 those are joined instead of just 15 features in the output. Tried this process manually in ArcGIS Pro and getting the desired results but not by using the script
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set the workspace to the geodatabase
env.workspace = "KPs.gdb"

# Define input and output feature classes
input_feature_class = "ChaRef_Pt"
join_feature_class = "Chaindbf"
output_feature_class = "StartK_pt"

# Define the join fields
input_join_field = "AbKp"
join_join_field = "StartK"

# Perform the join using arcpy.management.AddJoin (keep only matching records)
arcpy.management.AddJoin(input_feature_class, input_join_field, join_feature_class, join_join_field, "KEEP_COMMON")

# Create a feature layer to filter the joined features
output_feature_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_feature_class, "OutputFeatureLayer")

# Export the feature data (only matching records)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(output_feature_layer, env.workspace, output_feature_class)

# Add XY coordinates
arcpy.AddXY_management(output_feature_class)

# Define the coordinate system (British National Grid)
output_coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference(27700)
output_feature_class_path = f"{env.workspace}\\{output_feature_class}"
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(output_feature_class_path, output_coordinate_system)

print(f"{input_feature_class} was joined with {join_feature_class}, exported as {output_feature_class}, and XY coordinates were added with the British National Grid coordinate system.")

